# Azure Repos Git Integration with Azure Databricks

Tags: git, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I tried to link a notebook with a repository in Azure Repo. 
I have the same account in Azure Devops in Azure Databricks. I tried to make a link in the context of a notebook.
It doesn't work.

I have this error:

Error while syncing Git history: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')? at [Source: ???????? ?? ???????? ?? Azure DevOps Services | Sign In?? ???? ???? ??

Does someone understand this error and could help me?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs due to known issue where your Databricks and your Devops are in different AAD tenants which fails the passthrough sign in and blocks them from using the feature altogether.

Authentication with [Azure DevOps Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/?view=vsts) is done automatically when you authenticate using Azure Active Directory (Azure AD).

**Note:** The Azure DevOps Services organization must be linked to the same Azure AD tenant as Databricks -which means currently Databricks must be located in the same tenant as DevOps.

You may checkout [GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/49010) issue, which addressing similar issue.

For more information, see the Databricks documentation on [Azure DevOps Services integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/databricks/notebooks/azure-devops-services-version-control).

Comment: You're right. I did it. The problem continued. I was too impatient. It finally worked after a while. Thank you.